# .js-file being served with the contents of index.html when app deployed to cloud

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

When I run my application locally, everything works as expected, but when I deployed it to cloudno.de , it looks like [this](http://opensthlm.cloudno.de/).

I get an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` which is because the contents of `greeting.js` is

```
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en"> 
.......
```

Obivously not my javascript-file, but infact the contents of my index.html

My project is barely started and its using a Backbone Boilerplate, the code in its entirety can be viewed [here](http://gitweb.cloudno.de/git-web/gitweb.cgi?p=soroush.hakami/653-a0037b8636b049f3f7ca9e54d826089e.git;a=tree).

**Does anyone know what could possibly be the reason for this?**

My server.js:

```
// Require libraries 
var fs = require("fs");
var express = require("express");
var site = express.createServer();
// Determine which dist directory to use
var dir = process.argv.length > 2 && "./dist/" + process.argv[2];
// Use custom JS folder based off debug or release
dir && site.use("/assets/js", express.static(dir + "/js"));
dir && site.use("/assets/css", express.static(dir + "/css"));
// Serve static files
site.use("/app", express.static("./app"));
site.use("/assets", express.static("./assets"));
site.use("/dist", express.static("./dist"));
// Ensure all routes go home, client side app..
site.get("*", function(req, res) {
fs.createReadStream("./index.html").pipe(res);
});
site.listen(8000);
console.log("Server listening on http://localhost:8000");
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you copied and pasted this code? there did you get the `var dir = process.argv`... line?

The error could be due to the cloudno.de being initialized without arguments. Your app is looking for them on `process.arv`